# Can I install Gnome 3.24 Portland in Ubuntu 16.10?

Tags: gnome, updates

Right now I'm using Gnome 3.20.4 which came preinstalled with Ubuntu Gnome 16.10. 
I want to upgrade it to Gnome 3.24 which came out couple a weeks ago.

I've updated the software to the latest available one but Gnome 3.24 didn't came with it.

Do I need to add a PPA to get the new Gnome version?

[Gnome 3.24 Intro Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_Z1PAXiyTB0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot install or upgrade to GNOME 3.24 — at least, not yet. As this is open-source software it is perfectly feasible for someone to put in the effort required to maintain and distribute a GNOME 3.24 backport — but it’s highly unlikely anyone will

[Source](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/03/gnome-3-24-released-new-features)